# DEL or BACKSPACE not processed on overridden Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox::OnKeyPress

Tags: c++, .net, windows, textbox, clr

I´m building a custom `MaskedTextBox` that needs to accept just some types of characters. I had overridden the original class with the following code:

```
    ref class CustomMaskedTextBox : System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox
    {
        public:
            CustomMaskedTextBox();
            virtual void OnKeyPRess(System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) override;
    };

    CustomMaskedTextBox::CustomMaskedTextBox(void) {}
    CustomMaskedTextBox::~CustomMaskedTextBox(void) {}
    void CustomMaskedTextBox::OnKeyPress(System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e)
    {
        if ((e->KeyChar >= 'A' && e->KeyChar <= 'Z') ||
            (e->KeyChar >= '0' && e->KeyChar <= '9') ||
             e->KeyChar == '*' ||
             e->KeyChar == '-' ||
             e->KeyChar == '/' ||
             e->KeyChar == '.' ||
             e->KeyChar == ' ' ||
             e->KeyChar == (char) System::Windows::Forms::Keys::Back ||
             e->KeyChar == (char) System::Windows::Forms::Keys::Delete)
        {
            e->Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e->Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

For some reason the DEL and BACKSPACE keys are not being recognized, having no effect when texting on the object.

Help appreciated to make the DEL and BACKSPACE keys work.

Comment: The problem is that they **are** being recognized.  If you set the Handled property to *true* then you say that you handled it so the key no longer works.  Testing for A..Z etc is wrong as well, you must do that in the KeyPress event handler.  The entire event handler needs to be deleted.

Comment: Hans, I´ve changed the code to work with `KeyPress` according to your hint (see new code in post), but I´m still in trouble. DEL or BACKSPACE does not even call the handler....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What is your OS (windows/linux/mac)?
I  think this issue is related to the compiler. I ended up using Qt to recognize those keys (`Qt::Key_Delete`   `Qt::Key_Backspace`).

Comment: Windows 7. I´m using Visual Studio 2012. The key is recognized (I can see at the debug, but not processed after e->Handled = true).